# Google Universal Analytics Open Maps App Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

We've currently set up an event that tracks when a user clicks on an "Open in Mapps App" button, but it's not firing in Analytics after 24 hours or so. Here's what the code looks like. Any suggestions on where we're going wrong?

```
<a class="button map-app aligncenter" title="View in Maps App" href="https://google.com/maps/yp6z2" onclick="ga('send', 'event ', 'Open Maps App', 'On Click');" target="_blank" style="    margin-top: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;">Open in Maps App</a>
```

Comment: Try checking with GA Debugger to see if your hit is coming through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I c/p'ed your code into my site and ran it and saw this:

[image]

which shows that you have an extra space after "event" in

```
ga('send', 'event ', 'Open Maps App', 'On Click');
```

Remove the space and you should see the event hit go through.

Comment: That definitely was the issue. Thank you for finding that for me.